# ForEach PHP 5.4 and 5.3 Have Different Behaviors with MySQLi Object

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","", "mydb") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con)); 

$books = "select * from books";                                                         

$book_results = $mysqli->query($booked_pen_query);

$booked_arr = array();

foreach($book_results as $b){
    print_r($b);
    array_push($booked_arr, $b);
}
```

EXPECTED RESULT: `Array ([book_id] => 1 [book_name] => "abc") Array ([book_id] => 2 [book_name] => "xyz")`

It works on PHP 5.4.19 but the lower versions seem to show blank.

Question is: **How can I execute this code work in PHP 5.3?**

Comment: you realize that `$book_results` is a result **HANDLE**, and you need to `fetch()` rows of data from it? This would NEVER have worked as-is, regardless of PHP version.

Comment: Because you're using it wrong. According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) `->query` returns: *Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.*

Comment: this code is working with PHP version 5.4.19

Comment: Have you tried to test this code yet before you comment that it's wrong?

Comment: @MarcB - for SELECT queries `mysqli_query` returns `mysqli_result` which is traversable, which means that this code WILL work. See Example #1 at http://us1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour was changed in PHP 5.4 (https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)

> 5.4.0     Iterator support was added, as mysqli_result now implements Traversable.

To make it work in PHP 5.3:

```
while($b = $book_results->fetch_assoc()){
     print_r($b);
     array_push($booked_arr, $b);
}
```